# Section 508, Dragon readable table

Tags: html, html-table, section508

Does anyone know how to make the following table Dragon readable?
This is table that has number of rows in rowspan = 2.

Perhaps I placed the header in the wrong place.  The numberis the key to a row.

Could the existing table structure be 508 compliant or do I need something else?

```
    <table class="fullpage_brdr1"; id="complextable"?; summary="Currently Open"; style="text-align: center";>
    <thead>
                    <tr bgcolor="Gray"; class="sortLinks">
                        <th id ="h1" ?>
                            A
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h2" ?>
                            B
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h3" ?>
                            Region
                        </th>
                          <th id = "h4" ?>
                            C
                        </th>
                          <th id = "h5" ?>
                            D
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h6" ?>
                            E
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h7" ?>
                            F
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h8" ?>
                            G
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h9" ?>
                            H
                        </th>
                         <th id = "h10" ?>
                            I
                        </th>
                    </tr>
          </thead>          
                    <tbody title = "row">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2"; id="number">
                            999999999
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            Storage A
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            Boston
                        </td>

            <th id="expected"> Expected </th>

                            <th headers="number expected h5"> 50 </th>
                            <th headers="number expected h6"> 6,000 </th>
                            <th headers="number expected h7"> 5,000 </th>
                            <th headers="number expected h8"> $25,000 </th>


                            <td rowspan="2">
                            Partially Complete
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            This is test section for Remarks
                        </td>

                            <tr>           
                             <th id="processed"> Processed </th>
                            <th headers="EIN processed h5"> 50 </th>
                            <th headers="EIN processed h6"> 3,000 </th>
                            <th headers="EIN processed h7"> 4,000 </th>
                            <th headers="EIN processed h8"> $20,000 </th>




                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2"; id="number">
                            111111111
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            Storage B
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            Boston
                        </td>

            <th id="expected"> <a href="http://www.google.com">Expected</a> </th>

                            <th headers="number expected h5"> 70 </th>
                            <th headers="number expected h6"> 5,000 </th>
                            <th headers="number expected h7"> 5,000 </th>
                            <th headers="number expected h8"> $35,000 </th>



                        <td rowspan="2">
                            Partially Complete
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            This is test section for Remarks
                        </td>

                            <tr>           
                             <th id="processed"> <a href="http://www.google.com">Processed</a> </th>
                            <th headers="number processed h5"> 50 </th>
                            <th headers="number processed h6"> 2,000 </th>
                            <th headers="number processed h7"> 5,000 </th>
                            <th headers="number processed h8"> $40,000 </th>
                            </tr>
                </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Your markup is very wrong (there are no semicolons and question marks in HTML).

Comment: Like the other comments and answers, first you need to fix the HTML of the table so it constructed properly. [W3C HTML table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have way too many `<th>`'s in there, that is half of the issue. Some  assistive technology doesn't like merged cells (rowspan & colspan).

Try:

```
<table class="fullpage_brdr1" id="complextable" summary="Currently Open" style="text-align: center">
<thead>
  <tr bgcolor="Gray" class="sortLinks">
    <th id ="h1"> A </th>
    <th id = "h2"> B </th>
    <th id = "h3"> Region </th>
    <th id = "h4"> C </th>
    <th id = "h5"> D </th>
    <th id = "h6"> E </th>
    <th id = "h7"> F </th>
    <th id = "h8"> G </th>
    <th id = "h9"> H </th>
    <th id = "h10"> I </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" id="number"> 999999999 </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Storage A </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Boston </td>
    <th id="expected"> Expected </th>
    <td headers="number expected h5"> 50 </td>
    <td headers="number expected h6"> 6,000 </td>
    <td headers="number expected h7"> 5,000 </td>
    <td headers="number expected h8"> $25,000 </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Partially Complete </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> This is test section for Remarks </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="processed"> Processed </th>
    <td headers="EIN processed h5"> 50 </td>
    <td headers="EIN processed h6"> 3,000 </td>
    <td headers="EIN processed h7"> 4,000 </td>
    <td headers="EIN processed h8"> $20,000 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"; id="number"> 111111111 </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Storage B </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Boston </td>
    <th id="expected"> <a href="http://www.google.com">Expected</a> </th>
    <td headers="number expected h5"> 70 </td>
    <td headers="number expected h6"> 5,000 </td>
    <td headers="number expected h7"> 5,000 </td>
    <td headers="number expected h8"> $35,000 </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> Partially Complete </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> This is test section for Remarks </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="processed"> <a href="http://www.google.com">Processed</a> </th>
    <td headers="number processed h5"> 50 </td>
    <td headers="number processed h6"> 2,000 </td>
    <td headers="number processed h7"> 5,000 </td>
    <td headers="number processed h8"> $40,000 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```